# Dust.js - iterate through an iterated anonymous array

Tags: dust.js

I have this data structure in dust:

```
{ 'items' : [
    [ 'apples', "$1.00" , "Delicious" ],
    [ 'oranges', "$2.00" , "Juicy" ],
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the inner items, and can't figure out how.

I can address the entire array of the current loop via {.} , but i can't seem to access the items within it. ( I could do this in Mustache )

I was expecting something like this to work...

```
{#items}
   <b>{.[0]}</b> <em>only {.[1]}!</em>
   <p>{.[2]}</p>
{/items}
```

Comment: Your template and data works fine for me. I just plugged the template and data into the LinkedIn Dust playground here: http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your example in the dust playground: http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html

the output I got was:

```
<b>apples</b> <em>only $1.00!</em><p>Delicious</p><b>oranges</b> <em>only $2.00!</em><p>Juicy</p>
```

This looks to be what you were expecting. I believe fixes in this area after your post likely made this work. Grab the latest version of dust.